# PHP how to combine multiple if-statements into one function

Tags: php, if-statement

Based on a checkbox value this form will add subscribers to a corresponding list, but it can't save more than one value.

How do you merge, in order, to select and save more than one checkbox value?

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox_list']) && in_array('Austin Metro', $_POST['checkbox_list'])){
    $listID = '3';
    if ($listID){
        $indeed_mail->indeed_wysija_subscribe( $listID, $email );
    }
    break;
} else if(isset($_POST['checkbox_list']) && in_array('Central Austin', $_POST['checkbox_list'])){
    $listID = '4';
    if ($listID){
        $indeed_mail->indeed_wysija_subscribe( $listID, $email );
    }
    break;
} else if(isset($_POST['checkbox_list']) && in_array('Georgetown', $_POST['checkbox_list'])){
    $listID = '5';
    if ($listID){
        $indeed_mail->indeed_wysija_subscribe( $listID, $email );
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code?  How is it failing?  This looks like a valid `if` structure to me.

Comment: that belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I select all three checkboxes and submit form, only the first checkbox value is getting saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for... ?

```
$myValues = array('Austin Metro','Central Austin','Georgetown');
$myIds = array('3','4','5');

if (isset($_POST['checkbox_list']) && array_search($_POST['checkbox_list'], $myValues) !== false)
{
    $index = array_search($_POST['checkbox_list'], $myValues);
    $indeed_mail->indeed_wysija_subscribe( $myIds[$index], $email );
}
```

EDIT : I just read your comment above...

To grab your checkboxes as an array use :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_list[]" value="Austin Metro">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_list[]" value="Central Austin">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_list[]" value="Georgetown">
```

Then

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox_list'] as $check) 
{
    // do your stuff as explained above...
    if (isset(check) && array_search($check, $myValues) !== false)
    {
        $index = array_search($check, $myValues);
        $indeed_mail->indeed_wysija_subscribe( $myIds[$index], $email );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JBA! it worked really nice. The only thing i noticed is that is sending an email confirmation for each list (one email per list instead of one email with all lists) Any suggestions? Here's the indeed_wysija_subscribe() function.

Comment: public function indeed_wysija_subscribe( $listId, $e_mail, $first_name='', $last_name='' ){
   $user_data = array(
     'email' => $e_mail,
     'firstname' => $first_name,
     'lastname' => $last_name);
   $data = array(
     'user' => $user_data,
     'user_list' => array('list_ids' => array($listId))
   );
   $helper = &WYSIJA::get('user', 'helper');
   if($helper->addSubscriber($data)) return 1;
   else return 0;
  }

Comment: you could maybe build an array of listIds during the loop, then call your method after the loop and give it the built array...